# PHP: strcmp does not work?

Tags: php, passwords, strcmp

I was trying to read passwords from a textfile, and compare it to the password the user entered.
But although it appears to me that both word are exactly the same, my script says something else:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass']; //HTML form element with type="password"

$line;
$retrievedPassword = "";

$f = fopen("data/abc.log", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while(!feof($f)) { 
    $line = fgets($f);
    if (startsWith($line, $user)) {
      break; //password found
    }
}

fclose($f);

$var = explode(":", $line);
$retrievedPassword = $var[1];

echo $pass." ".$retrievedPassword; // example: password password

if (strcmp($pass, $var[1]) == 0) {
    header('Location: user.php'); //never the case
}else {
    //header('Location: index.php');
}


function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}
```

Is the password encrypted or something like that or why does this code not work?

Comment: Try to use `var_dump($pass)` and `var_dump($retrievedPassword)`.  Maybe there are some extra characters in there.

Comment: "trying to read passwords from a textfile" - I hope this is just a test. Not exactly secure.

Comment: Does `$pass === $retrievedPassword` work?

Comment: `fgets()` returns the EOF (end of file) and maybe the end of line, checking with `var_dump` is a good idea

Comment: Also, is there a linebreak on the line you're retrieving from the text file?

Comment: Beyond the `strcmp` issue, don't do that. Don't reinvent the wheel, use consistent authentication tools, and don't store plain or weak hashed password anywhere.

Comment: Follow the suggestion from @Rocket Hazmat and share with us the output, if you cannot resolve it on your own.

Comment: Just a note, `if (startsWith($line, $user))` will not necessarily find you the correct line if you have one username that's a prefix of another. If colon is the separator and not allowed in usernames, you should filter it out of the user input and then use `if (startsWith($line, "$user:"))` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from a file, always assume 'mess' to be in there. Especially text files often have different line separators depending on which program on which OS was used to edit them - historically Windows uses CRLF, Mac CR and *nix variants LF, but modern editors like Notepad2 and Notepad++ allow you to configure them.

Before exploding the line on the colon separator, use trim() to remove any extraneous whitespace like obsolete line separators and trailing spaces/tabs.

As a side note on debugging: remember that you are outputting HTML to a browser, which silently collapses all whitespace. To look for reasons why 2 strings are not identical, wrap the echo statement in apostrophes (`echo "'$sample1' '$sample2'";`), or use var_dump as suggested by Rocket Hazmat, or output it in a `<pre>` section. Also, if the strings look identical in output, doublecheck with strlen to know there's no 'mess' in there.

Answer (score 1):

is the password hash. You do not need to use strcmp .Simple way is:

```
if($pass == $var[1]))
```

have fun

Comment: Thank you. I did try this first, but instead of using $var[1], I used $retrievedPassword and that wasn't the same. Somehow. Well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump to check what's in your $haystack and $needle inside startsWith()

Also note that your startsWith() is broken - it would return true if the line is "bookworm:bob" but the user entered the password "book". You should (at the very least!) add a line like this:

```
function startsWithPassword($haystack, $needle)
{
    $needle .= ':';
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}
```

So then you are trying to match 'enteredpassword:' against the beginning of the line.

Of course, if users put colons into their passwords you're still stuck...

If you look up and learn about salting and hashing passwords and then you'll be a happier coder with a more secure site!